# PRG - understanding the definition

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

Say $G$ is a $PRG$ that expands its input by a single bit, so we define:
$$G'(x_1||x_2)=G(x_1)||G(x_2)$$
The exercise states to prove that $G'$ is also a PRG.
Now here is my confusion. $PRGs$ are defined for random seeds as input.

But as an adversary I know $G$. So for $x\in\{0,1\}^*$ I could always input
$$x||x$$
And now, I can check if both halves of $G'(x||x)=G(x)||G(x)$ are equal and know that this isn't random.

In the solution they assume that $x_1,x_2$ must be randomly selected as well. But then what is the point of an adversary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The adversary must not be allowed to choose the seed.**
<sub>(Otherwise, the definition would be trivially unsatisfiable, as the adversary could just check whether the returned string is $G(x)$ for their chosen seed $x$.)</sub>

The rationale behind this is that a PRG's seed is understood as (some kind of) a secret key, which the attacker must not be able to know or choose in *any* threat model. (After all, that's why the secret key is *secret*. Note that *any* cryptography trivially breaks when the attacker gets their hand on the key(s).)

By definition, a function $G\colon \{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^{\ell(n)}$ with $\ell(n)>n$ is a pseudorandom generator (PRG) if any polynomial-time adversary is unable to differentiate between a truly random $y\in\{0,1\}^{\ell(n)}$ and the pseudorandom string $G(x)$ for a random seed $x\in\{0,1\}^n$ except for negligible probability.

Intuitively, what this entails is that the output of a PRG, when initialized with a sufficiently random seed, is **"just as good" as a real random string.**

Answer (score 2):

My assumptions regarding the adversary were wrong!
The adversary doesn't have the ability to request for the output of $G$ on some seed $s$.
The test goes as follows:

1. We sample randomly a seed $s$ and compute $s'=G(s)$
2. We then give the adversary our $s'$.
3. The adversary outputs 1 if $s'$ is in the world of $G$, or 0 otherwise.